# PowerQueryConnection into the Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sharepoint, office365

I am trying the retrieve/download a `.csv` file from the `.odc` file via Sharepoint (Office 365).

The below is the connection string which is used by the powerquery connection parameter from `.odc` connection string (this is usually used in Excel for the powerqueryconnection to retrieve the data):

```
<xml id=msodc>
    <odc:OfficeDataConnection
         xmlns:odc="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:odc"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
        <odc:PowerQueryConnection odc:Type="OLEDB">
            <odc:ConnectionString>Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=&quot;GetViewData?ListViewID=52&amp;csvformat=true&quot;;Extended Properties=&quot;&quot;
            </odc:ConnectionString>
            <odc:CommandType>SQL</odc:CommandType>
            <odc:CommandText>SELECT * FROM [GetViewData?ListViewID=52&amp;csvformat=true]</odc:CommandText>
        </odc:PowerQueryConnection>
    </odc:OfficeDataConnection>
</xml>
```

I want to extract the csv file which is this connecting to pandas dataframe. I tried the below code but not able to work it out

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect('Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=&quot;GetViewData?ListViewID=52&amp;csvformat=true&quot;;Extended Properties=&quot;&quot')

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM [GetViewData?ListViewID=52&amp;csvformat=true]", conn)

conn.close()
```

please help,
thanks in advance

Comment: does this work for SP? IIUC SP correctly you need to use an API endpoint to consume data from there, I usually use the Graph API which is v.handy

Comment: Thanks for the response.No it does not work and the admin team not giving endpoint.Here application connect the data via .odc connection and exports automatically to export in csv format. It’s  using the PowerQuery.
Do you have any other way to get the data via this connection string?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'Path where the Excel file is stored\File name.xlsx', sheet_name='your Excel sheet name')
print(df)
```

The above code might be useful for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Ashish. Here I am retrieve data from the .odc connecting into DataFrame  not from excel .